# I'm Still Standing and I Will Return

Tags: riddle, word, affix-riddle

My first is hot.
My last is cold.
In the middle, lies a road.

Altogether, I'm both shortest and longest.

What am I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The word is

> **SOLSTICE**

---

My first is hot.

> **SOL** is latin for sun, which is hot

My last is cold.

> **ICE** is cold

In the middle, lies a road.

> **ST** meaning street, a type of road

Altogether, I'm both shortest and longest.

> The winter and summer solstice is the longest and shortest day of the year!

And for the title (Credit to @cap):

> On the day of solstice the sun stops moving south/north, pauses, and then moves in the opposite direction - hence standing still, and then returning.
>
> Solstice literally means [sun standing still](https://www.etymonline.com/word/solstice), and it "will return" as there are 2 solstices a year.

Comment: Not sure on the title though I feel like its relevant?

Comment: Re the title, I'm thinking of connections with rot13(FGNAQVAT fgbarf, naq gur ERGHEA bs gur fha)

Comment: @Beastly Gerbil Concerning the title, the word you found means rot13(fha fgnaqvat fgvyy naq vg unccraf evtug orsber gur fha erirefrf vgf pbhefr.)

Comment: @cap ah yep that makes the most sense, I never knew that!

Comment: @Stiv I think cap has it bang on, must admit never knew about the return bit!